# Define react redux state with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js, react-redux

I have todoReducer.ts file like this

```
import ActionType from "../types";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

interface Item {
  task: string;
  priority: string;
  id: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  label: string;
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.ADD_ITEM:
      return { ...state, items: [action.payload, ...state.items] };

    case ActionType.CROSS_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map((e: Item) => {
          if (e.id === action.payload) e.isActive = false;
          return e;
        }),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default reducer;
```

Then the root reducer like this

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import todoReducer from "./todoReducer";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  todo: todoReducer,
});

export default reducers;

export type State = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;
```

In my todoList.jsx file

```
    import {State} from "../store/reducers/index"
    const TodoList = ()=>{
     const items = useSelector((state:State) => state.todo.items);
...

    }
```

This gives me an error

> Property 'items' does not exist on type 'never'.

Seems initialState's `items` object not recognizing by the ts.

How do I fix this issue?

**Updated**
After the comment, I have added the

```
export type State = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

But I hover over the store.getState it says the same error. I think still it doesn't pick the type
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should declare type when `createStore`

```
const store = createStore(reducers, ...)
export type State = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Comment: Hi Update the question I think that place also it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should update typw for `initialState` when create `reducer`

```
const initialState: Array<Item > = {
  items: [],
};
```